# Modify cart view to allow direct quantity updates

Tags: 7, commerce, ajax

In want to modify the cart view so that when costumer change quantity of item in cart, it will update cart and total price automatically and immediately through AJAX (instead of when pressing button update cart through page reload).

Answer (score 0):

The short, general, answer is: use the [Forms Ajax API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7). It’s difficult to provide a longer answer here. Another respondent may know of a commerce module that does this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that